# looking for a location of window add-on

Tags: add-on

Could someone post an active link to the latest version of window generator add on please? I have looked for the last hour and while many links go to a dropbox site the links are all removed.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found one. Here's the link for anyone else looking: https://github.com/Antonioya/blender/blob/master/add_window_3/add_window_3.zip